# How can I use qnorm on Rcpp?

Tags: r, inline, rcpp

```
require(inline)
func <- cxxfunction(, 'return Rcpp::wrap( qnorm(0.95,0.0,1.0) );' ,plugin="Rcpp")
```

*error: no matching function for call to ‘qnorm5(double, int, int)’*

```
require(inline)
func <- cxxfunction(, 'return Rcpp::wrap( qnorm(0.95, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0) );' 
                   ,plugin="Rcpp")
```

*error: no matching function for call to ‘qnorm5(double, double, double, int, int)’*

```
require(inline)
code <-'
double a = qnorm(0.95, 0.0, 1.0);
return  Rcpp::wrap( a );
' 
func <- 
cxxfunction(, code ,plugin="Rcpp")
func()
```

*error: no matching function for call to ‘qnorm5(double, double, double)’*

How can I use qnorm on Rcpp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By making the `mean` and `sd` arguments `double` as the error message shows -- so try this is a full example

```
library(inline)
f <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric", plugin="Rcpp", body='
     Rcpp::NumericVector x(xs);
     return Rcpp::wrap(Rcpp::qnorm(x, 1.0, 0.0));
')
```

and have a look at the examples and unit tests -- I just looked this up in the unit test file `runit.stats.R` which has a lot of test cases for these statistical 'Rcpp sugar' functions.

***Edit on 2012-11-14:***   With Rcpp 0.10.0 released today, you can call do the signature `R::qnorm(double, double, double, int, int)` if you want to use C-style code written against `Rmath.h`. Rcpp sugar still gives you vectorised versions.

Comment: require(inline)
    func <- cxxfunction(, 'qnorm(0.95, 1.0, 0.0);' ,plugin="Rcpp")

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘qnorm5(double, double, double)’

Comment: Could you paste it on your R for test?

Comment: Sorry, first arg has to be a vector -- expanded my post with a tested example.

Comment: It works well. It's my honor to get the answer from "DIRK" itself. Thank you.