# Use pnorm from Rmath.h with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to write a piece of C++ code with Rcpp using functions like pnorm and qnorm. I can use the Rcpp sugar versions of these for vectors as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738848/567015, but I don't need to do this on a vector but just on a double.

If I understand correctly I can use the `Rf_` prefix to get the scalar versions from Rmath.h. However, `Rf_pnorm` doesn't work:

```
library("inline")
Src <-  '
double y = as<double>(x);
double res = Rf_pnorm(y,0.0,1.0);
return wrap(res) ;
'

fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "numeric") ,Src, plugin = "Rcpp" )

fx(1)
```

Gives as errors:

```
file10c81a585dee.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* file10c81a585dee(SEXP)':
file10c81a585dee.cpp:32:32: error: 'Rf_pnorm' was not declared in this scope
```

I found after some googling and trial and error that `Rf_pnorm5` does work but requires extra parameters for lower tail and log scale:

```
Src <-  '
double y = as<double>(x);
double res = Rf_pnorm5(y,0.0,1.0,1,0);
return wrap(res) ;
'

fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "numeric") ,Src, plugin = "Rcpp" )

fx(1)
## [1] 0.8413447
```

Great, but I don't understand why this works but `Rf_pnorm` doesn't. I rather use `Rf_pnorm` because I think that makes it easier to find the right codes for different distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Rcpp sugar variant which is more natural with Rcpp:

```
R> library(inline)
R> 
R> Src <- '
+ NumericVector y = NumericVector(x);
+ NumericVector res = pnorm(y,0.0,1.0);
+ return res;
+ '
R> 
R> fx <-  cxxfunction( signature(x = "numeric") , body=Src, plugin = "Rcpp")
R> 
R> fx(seq(0.8, 1.2, by=0.1))
[1] 0.788145 0.815940 0.841345 0.864334 0.884930
R> 
R> fx(1.0)      ## can also call with scalar args
[1] 0.841345
R>
```

Looking more closely at our headers, we undefine the `pnorm` et al from `Rmath.h` in order to define the (vectorised) variants you get from Rcpp sugar.

***Edit on 2012-11-14:***   With Rcpp 0.10.0 released today, you can call do the signature `R::pnorm(double, double, double, int, int)` if you want to use C-style code written against `Rmath.h`. Rcpp sugar still gives you vectorised versions.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is easiest to use the Rcpp sugar version indeed. Found a workaround with `pnorm(NumericVector(1,y),0.0,1.0)[0]` which seems to work fine.

Comment: You shouldn't need that. The `fx()` function I posted can be called with a scalar too -- remember that all R objects are vectors, sometimes of length one.