# Fast pnorm() computation on really long vector (of length ~1e+7 to ~1e+8)

Tags: c++, r, random

Is there a way to optimize `pnorm`? I am having some bottleneck in my code and after a lot a optimization and benchmark I realized that it comes from the call to `pnorm` on really big vectors.

With `microbenchmarking` I got on my machine that if `length(u) ~ 5e+7` then `pnorm(u)` takes 11 seconds.

Is there a way to use Rcpp here, or the built-in `pnorm` is already optimized ?

Any ideas welcomed.

I have found these posts on SO: [Use pnorm from Rmath.h with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805100/use-pnorm-from-rmath-h-with-rcpp) and [How can I use qnorm on Rcpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738619/how-can-i-use-qnorm-on-rcpp/9738848#9738848). But as far as I understood their purpose is to use the R functions into Cpp code.

Comment: Depending on your use case and your need for accuracy you might be able to (1) use an adequate but faster approximation to `pnorm` (2) "memoise", i.e. store some results in a lookup table.  e.g. an old-school approximation to `pnorm` is `plogis` with an appropriately matched variance ...

Comment: e.g. [this](http://www.jiem.org/index.php/jiem/article/viewFile/60/27) looks useful ...

Comment: Approximation is a good idea I guess, especially after @ZheyuanLi response.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi if I use first `round(u, digits=3)` and then `pnorm(unique(u))` what would then be an efficient way to recompute the original `sum(pnorm(u))` ?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I thought of the same trick with `rle(sort(...`, apparently faster, but the computational overhead to *prepare* the data makes it longer in the end. On your example, microbenchmarking gives x20 longer than just `pnorm`

Comment: In this context yes, it will always be

Comment: Ok great news this 5 to 6x improvement. Eager to try it, I'm on my phone now, I'll post new question as soon as I can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this session, I am going to demonstrate fast yet accurate approximation to `pnorm()`.

Before we start, we need to be clear: what do we want to achieve by using approximation? Efficiency / speed / performance, right? But where would such efficiency come from?

As discussed above, `pnorm()` computation is memory-bound; even if we do approximate computation, it is still memory-bound (hence we don't consider further parallelization). Memory-bound problems have

```
number of floating point operations : memory access = O(1)
```

In other words, this ratio is some constant `C`. So our aim should be to reduce this constant, i.e., we want to reduce floating point operations.

Number of floating operations are often reported as the number of floating points addition and multiplication. Other types of floating point operations are "converted" to such measure. Now, let's compare the costs of several common floating point operations.

```
u <- sample(1:10/10, 5e+7, replace = TRUE)

system.time(u + u)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.468   0.168   0.639 
system.time(u * u)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.424   0.212   0.638 
system.time(u / u)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.504   0.204   0.710 
system.time(u ^ 1.1)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 7.240   0.212   7.458 
system.time(sqrt(u))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.044   0.176   2.224 
system.time(exp(u))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 4.336   0.208   4.550 
system.time(log(u))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.748   0.172   2.925 
system.time(round(u))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 6.836   0.188   7.034
```

Note that addition and multiplication are cheap, root and logarithm are more expensive, while some operations are very expensive, including power, exponential and rounding.

Now let's get back to `pnorm()`, or even `dnorm()`, etc, where we have an exponential term to compute. Given that:

```
system.time(pnorm(u))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 11.016   0.160  11.193 
system.time(dnorm(u))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 8.844   0.164   9.022
```

we see that the majority of time to compute `pnorm()` and `dnorm()` are attribute to computing exponential. `pnorm()` takes longer time than `dnorm()` because it further has an integral!

**Now, our goal is fairly clear: we want to replace the expensive `pnorm()` evaluation with something really cheap, ideally only involving addition / multiplication. Can we??**

There have been many approximation methods in history. @Ben has mentioned the logistic approximation. R function `plogis()` does this. But a careful read on `?plogis` shows that it is still based on exponentials.

Now, instead of using those parametric approximation, can we do non-parametric approximation? But we should not be doing regression here; instead, we want to use some interpolation function of fine resolution accurate data, to predict `pnorm()`. Well, linear interpolation is the best choice, as it is super efficient (due to sparsity: the linear predictor matrix is tri-diagonal). In R, `approx` does this. I refer reader unfamiliar with this to `?approx`, and I will simply proceed.

The OP says he only needs standard normal distribution, so we focus on this. Consider the following approximate function (I did not use `approxfun` because I want customizable `h`):

```
approx.pnorm <- function(u, h = 0.2) {
  x <- seq(from = -4, to = 4, by = h)
  approx(x, pnorm(x), yleft = 0, yright = 1, xout = u)$y
  }
```

The accurate data are taken on a grid of resolution `h` between `[-4, 4]`. Predictions below `-4` is 0, while predictions beyond `4` is 1. This satisfies the requirement of a CDF. Given new values `u`, we approximate `pnorm(u)` by linear interpolation based on known accurate data.

Obviously, the resolution `h` controls accuracy. Consider the following function to compute RMSE and display approximation curve:

```
RMSEh <- function(h) {
  x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
  y <- pnorm(x)
  y1 <- approx.pnorm(x, h)
  plot(x, y, type = "l", lwd = 2); lines(x, y1, col = 2, lwd = 2)
  mean((y - y1) ^ 2)^0.5
  }

par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
RMSEh(1)  # 0.01570339
RMSEh(0.5)  # 0.003968882
RMSEh(0.2)  # 0.000639888
```

[image: approx]

Actually, when `h = 0.2`, approximation is already fairly good. So we will use `h = 0.2` in the following.

---

**Benchmarking**

This should be the most exciting part. In above we have seen that accurate computation of `pnorm(u)` takes 11 seconds. Now

```
system.time(approx.pnorm(u, h = 0.2))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.656   0.172   2.833
```

Wow, we are nearly 4 times faster!!

Comment: approach is interesting, but using `microbenchmark` I got the same order of magnitude for both, ie 3.≈ seconds:
`> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(pnorm(u), approx.pnorm(u))
Unit: seconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        pnorm(u) 2.966394 3.149768 3.571884 3.326649 3.696174 6.855846   100
 approx.pnorm(u) 2.730123 2.890056 3.225221 3.012693 3.197080 6.546609   100`

Comment: that's lots different form yours indeed:
`> system.time(u + u) 0.178       0.787       1.290 
> system.time(u * u) 0.140       0.148       0.312 
> system.time(u / u) 0.466       0.139       0.611 
> system.time(u ^ 1.1) 2.303       0.145       2.460 
> system.time(sqrt(u))  0.448       0.157       0.767 
> system.time(exp(u)) 0.709       0.163       0.918 
> system.time(log(u)) 0.849       0.146       1.006 
> system.time(round(u)) 1.015       0.140       1.160`

Comment: same `u` as yours. I'm on 2,4 GHz Intel Core i5 from 2011 with 4Go Ram and 128Go SSD for hard drive

Comment: in any case, I guess this approach is definitely to be kept in mind for other problems I might encounter

Comment: finally implemented this solutio for use on another computer, thanks !

Comment: for use on computers with same performances as yours; i'm sharing my code with fellows

Answer (score 2):

I am not here to disappoint you, but `pnorm` is already optimized. If you type "pnorm" in your R console, you see how it is written:

```
function (q, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
.Call(C_pnorm, q, mean, sd, lower.tail, log.p)
<bytecode: 0x98712e0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

It is already written in C (see `Rmath.h`).

Some people might then suggest you to do parallel computing. R level parallelism can use, for example, `mclapply` / `parLapply` / `parSapply` function from `parallel` package. But whether you should do this depends on what hardware you have.

It is a bad idea to parallelize `pnorm()` on a simple multi-core machine, as it is **memory-bound**. The ratio between CPU computation and memory reference is `O(1)` (using the big `O` notation). Furthermore, R level parallelism is not thread-level parallelism, but by setting up independent R processes. This means, parallel overhead is greater and not easy to be amortised.

If you have a cluster, you can do parallel computing on different nodes for really large problem. You will get good parallel scalability.

---

**Further clarification on parallel processing**

Assume `u` is a long vector: `u[1], u[2], ....` and we aim to compute `pnorm(u)`. Each element `u[i]` is only brought from RAM to CPU once without a second use. Therefore, computation of `pnorm()` requires constant data read.

Now consider a multi-core machine with 4 physical CPUs (i.e., each with non-shared execution units, like registers, ALU, FPU, L1 cache, etc). We set up 4 threads or processes hoping to run 4 parallel `pnorm()` computation on 4 different chunks of `u`. During computation, every CPU is "data-hungry", and asking for constant data flow. However, there is only a single bus. If one CPU is occupying the bus, data flow for the rest three are cut off hence they have nothing to do. In other words, those 4 CPUs can almost never work at the same time, and they are no better than single CPU computation.

Now we move on to 4 nodes on a cluster. After initial data split to 4 different nodes, each node will be working in a single CPU mode. There is neither shared execution resources nor memory resources between 4 nodes. They can work completely parallel. In the end, results from 4 nodes are forged together. In this way, for really large problem, good / reasonable scalability can be guaranteed.

Parallel computing on multi-core machine is only useful for **CPU-bound** task (up to some extent, before bus becomes saturated). Specifically, we should use block algorithm for L1 caching. Caching achieves considerable data reuse. For example, for block matrix multiplication of block size `nb`, the ratio between CPU work and memory read is `O(nb)`. In this way, after a CPU reading a block of data into its exclusive L1 cache, in comparatively a long period of time (in CPU cycles) it does not require access to RAM, so the bus becomes free. Then the other cores can take such gap / break to read the data they required. As only as only a limited number of CPUs are used, they can work in an interleave manner without mutual interference.

Comment: nice answer. How do you know that `pnorm()` is memory-bound ... ?

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I do use `foreach` package to, but couldn't imagine that `doMC` couldn't help while `doMPI` does

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit surprised that the linear introplation shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38029401/5861244) is so slow. A solution is to use [this package](https://github.com/boennecd/fastncdf) instead (created by Yixuan Qiu and updated by me) to do the interpolation. It can be installed by calling:

```r
remotes::install_github("boennecd/fastncdf")
```

#### Updated version of old answer

In what follows is my old answer along with a new approximation using the `fastncdf` package.

> Is there a way to use Rcpp here, or the built-in `pnorm` is already optimized ?

You can go with an approximation like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38029401/5861244). However, `pnorm` does seem to benefit from computation in parallel at least on my machine. Here is an example using OpenMP:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <cmath>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

/**
 * evaluates the standard normal CDF after avoiding some checks in the
 * original version. Use with care!
 */
inline double pnorm_std(double const x, int lower, int is_log) {
  if(std::isinf(x) || std::isnan(x))
    return NAN;

  double p, cp;
  p = x;
  Rf_pnorm_both(x, &p, &cp, lower ? 0 : 1, is_log);
  return lower ? p : cp;
}

/** calls pnorm_std potentially in parallel. */
// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
Rcpp::NumericVector pnorm_std(Rcpp::NumericVector x,
                              unsigned const n_threads = 1){
  R_len_t const n = x.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector out(n);
  double const * const xb = &x[0];
  double * const ob = &out[0];

#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads) schedule(static)
#endif
  for(R_len_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    *(ob + i) = pnorm_std(*(xb + i), 1L, 0L);

  return out;
}
```

Using `Rcpp::sourceCpp` on the above, we can now compare the computation time and precision/that we get the same:

```r
# simulate data
set.seed(1)
u <- rnorm(1e7)

# assign function to compare with from other answer
approx_pnorm <- function(u, h = 0.2) {
  x <- seq(from = -4, to = 4, by = h)
  approx(x, pnorm(x), yleft = 0, yright = 1, xout = u)$y
}


# check times and results. First using the new interpolation method
library(fastncdf)
system.time(lin_itr <- fastpnorm(u))
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.068   0.016   0.084 

# w/ pre-allocated vector
dum <- rep(0., length(u))
system.time(fastpnorm_preallocated(u, p = dum))
all.equal(lin_itr, dum)
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.058   0.000   0.058 

# then as in the original answer
system.time(truth <- pnorm(u))
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.368   0.008   0.376 
system.time(mini_one <- pnorm_std(u, 1L))
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.265   0.016   0.281
system.time(mini_six <- pnorm_std(u, 4L))
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.265   0.024   0.092 
system.time(other_ans <- approx_pnorm(u, h = 0.2))
#R>    user  system elapsed 
#R>   0.272   0.004   0.277 

# are the results identical?
all.equal(mini_one, truth)
#R> [1] TRUE
all.equal(other_ans, truth)
#R> [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.001062221"
all.equal(lin_itr, truth)
#R> [1] "Mean relative difference: 8.765925e-08"

# what about the times?
bench::mark(`R                ` = pnorm       (u),
            `C++ (1 thread)   ` = pnorm_std   (u, 1L),
            `C++ (2 threads)  ` =  pnorm_std  (u, 2L),
            `C++ (4 threads)  ` =  pnorm_std  (u, 4L),
            `C++ (6 threads)  ` =  pnorm_std  (u, 6L),
            `Other answer     ` = approx_pnorm(u, h = 0.2),
            `C++ interpolation` = fastpnorm   (u),
            min_time = 10, relative = TRUE, check = FALSE)
#R> # A tibble: 7 x 13
#R>   expression          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                  time           gc                
#R>   <bch:expr>        <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                  <list>         <list>            
#R> 1 R                  5.23   5.01      1         1        1.33    21     6      7.84s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [27]>  <tibble [27 × 3]> 
#R> 2 C++ (1 thread)     3.96   3.82      1.31      1        1.53    28     7      7.95s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [35]>  <tibble [35 × 3]> 
#R> 3 C++ (2 threads)    2.18   2.10      2.39      1        2.06    54    10      8.43s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [64]>  <tibble [64 × 3]> 
#R> 4 C++ (4 threads)    1.29   1.26      3.98      1        2.62    92    13      8.63s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [105]> <tibble [105 × 3]>
#R> 5 C++ (6 threads)    1      1         5.01      1        3.48   114    17      8.49s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [131]> <tibble [131 × 3]>
#R> 6 Other answer       3.86   3.76      1.33      1.00     1       31     5      8.68s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [11 × 3]> <bch:tm [36]>  <tibble [36 × 3]> 
#R> 7 C++ interpolation  1.13   1.08      4.61      1        3.07   105    15      8.49s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 × 3]>  <bch:tm [120]> <tibble [120 × 3]>
```

There is a five fold reduction in the computation time using six threads on my six core machine. Clearly, though, it does not scale linearly. Moreover, the answer I cited earlier is not yielding that big of a reduction with 70 million variables and it is not that precise (I hope that I did not make an error). The new C++ version from fastncdf is almost as fast as using six threads with the Rcpp solution.

Comment: ```fastncdf``` is twice slower than ```pnorm```.

Comment: The examples on the Github page shows that the package is almost 10x faster. Can you give an example where this is not true?