# R Rcpp define qnorm function

Tags: c++, r, distribution, rcpp

I am having issues calling `qnorm` using Rcpp in R

The `rnorm` function works in R just fine:

```
library(Rcpp); p <- 0.8

# create rnorm_cpp function ----
cppFunction('NumericVector rnorm_cpp(int n, double mean, double sd) { 
return Rcpp::rnorm(n, mean, sd); }')

# test function ----
set.seed(1); n <- 10e3
mean(rnorm_cpp(n,2,3)) # returns ~ 2
sd(rnorm_cpp(n,2,3)) # returns ~ 3
```

However, if I do the same for qnorm:

```
# create qnorm_cpp function ----
cppFunction('NumericVector qnorm_cpp(double p, double mean, double sd) { 
return Rcpp::qnorm(p, mean, sd); }')
```

I get the following error: `Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, : Error 1 occurred building shared library.`

How can I modify this code to get it to work? Thank you.

I would expect `qnorm_cpp(p, 2, 3)` to work in the same way as `qnorm(p, 2, 3)` which, in this case, produces a value of `4.524864`

Comment: I think `p` needs to be a `NumericVector`, not a `double`. Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738848/5977215

Comment: Hi SymbolixAU - Not sure I understand. How would it be defined differently from the rnorm function defined above? How would the syntax be different?

Comment: `qnorm_cpp(NumericVector p, double mean, double sd)`

Comment: If you're using only one value, you might want to use `::qnorm()` instead.

Comment: There are multiple writeups on the fact that we have _both_ the *scalar* versions in the R namespace, ie `R::qnorm()` _and_ the Rcpp sugar vectorised version `Rcpp::qnorm()`.  Same for `rnorm and all the others.  See example on the Rcpp Gallery and other places.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I definitely want the functions to take vector inputs so I want to use `Rcpp::qnorm()`. I don't understand why I wouldn't be defining `mean` and `sd` as `NumericVector` too, however...i.e. `qnorm_cpp(NumericVector p, NumericVector mean, NumericVector sd)`. The help says that `mean` and `sd` are vector inputs in the same way that `q` is.